# fsharp function doesn't return anything

Tags: recursion, f#

I have the following smaller tokenizer for simple arithmetic expressions. I am new to fsharp and I don't know why this function doesn't return anything when being called. Can someone please help?

```
let tokenizer s = 
  let chars1 = scan s
  let rec repeat list = 
    match list with
    | []->[]
    | char::chars ->
      match char with
      | ')' -> RP::repeat chars
      | '(' -> LP::repeat chars
      | '+' -> Plus::repeat chars
      | '*' -> Times::repeat chars
      | '^' -> Pow::repeat chars
      | _ -> 
        let (x,y) = makeInt (toInt char) chars
        Int x::repeat chars
  repeat chars1
```

Comment: Do you have any sample input and expected output?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek If I enter something like 1+2, I should at least have some output. But now my code doesn't have any output.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger? Looking at the code, it seems that the only way repeat can return an empty list is if list is empty when repeat is called the first time which would imply that your scan function is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `scan`, `toInt`, `makeInt` and the union type for the expression was not presented, but might be inferred as:

```
let scan (s:string) = s.ToCharArray() |> Array.toList
let toInt c = int c - int '0'
let makeInt n chars = (n,chars)

type expr = RP | LP | Plus | Times | Pow | Int of int

let tokenizer s = 
  let chars1 = scan s
  let rec repeat list = 
    match list with
    | []->[]
    | char::chars ->
      match char with
      | ')' -> RP::repeat chars
      | '(' -> LP::repeat chars
      | '+' -> Plus::repeat chars
      | '*' -> Times::repeat chars
      | '^' -> Pow::repeat chars
      | _ -> 
        let (x,y) = makeInt (toInt char) chars
        Int x::repeat chars
  repeat chars1
```

in which case:

```
tokenizer "1+1"
```

gives:

```
val it : expr list = [Int 1; Plus; Int 1]
```

It's possible the issue is in the implementation of your scan function.